# Excel VBA: Consolidate the iterating group in "For Each" block

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I found the concatenation/appending of two arrays to be a too cumbersome process for my example. But how to iterate through two arrays of sheets using For Each in a single block (how to shorten the following code)?

```
arr1 = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
arr2 = Array("Sheet5", "Sheet6")

For Each sh In Sheets(arr1)
sh.Visible = True
Next sh

For Each sh In Sheets(arr2)
sh.Visible = True
Next sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always **combine** your small arrays into a **super** array.  For example:

```
Sub Klai()
    arr1 = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    arr2 = Array("Sheet5", "Sheet6")

    arr3 = Array(arr1, arr2)

    For Each a In arr3
        For Each b In a
            MsgBox Sheets(b).Name
            Sheets(b).Visible = True
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Not bad if you have a lot of arrays. I was hoping for something even simpler.

Comment: @Klaidonis  Well if you have many short arrays, you can combine them into a single super array and still use only **1** nested loop-pair.

Comment: *(+1)* Nice! The only problem I have with this solution is that we have (in the end) lots of variables of type `variant` containing arrays of an undefined range. This is due to the fact that the `array` function [requires](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx) the variables to be of type `variant`.

Comment: @Ralph  There may be ways to avoid this disadvantage.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in yet another solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tmpSO()

Dim lngItem As Long
Dim strArray() As String
Dim strOneLongList As String
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

'Your starting point
arr1 = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
arr2 = Array("Sheet5", "Sheet6")

'Bring all of them together into one long string containing all sheets
strOneLongList = Join(arr1, "/") & "/" & Join(arr2, "/")
MsgBox "This is what strOneLongList currently looks like:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & strOneLongList

'Convert the list into a string array with four elements
strArray = Split(Join(arr1, "/") & "/" & Join(arr2, "/"), "/")

For lngItem = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strArray(lngItem)).Visible = True
Next lngItem

End Sub
```

Explanations:

1. The [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h(v=vs.90).aspx) functions brings all elements of an array together into one long string.
2. The [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function is very similar to the [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx) function you originally used. Yet, array requires that you list the items in separate strings delimited by commas. Split expects one long string in which one character is chosen to separate all elements.

<sub>*Caution: Choose the character wisely you are using in a split list to separate all elements in that list and make sure that this character can never be found in any element of the list. I chose the `/` character because it cannot be used in a name for a sheet. Alternative characters could be `\` or `*` or something very exotic like `ChrW(12484)`.*</sub>

It is certainly not as simplistic (and thereby possibly "visually appealing") as the other solution provided by @Garys-Student. Yet, this solution avoids the `Arrays` function and thereby we can bypass the variables of type `variant`. The same applies to the `For Each...` loop. It requires also variables of type `variant` or `object`. So, I replaced this one too with a `For ... Next` loop.

I am not sure if I'd use this construction or the other solution. Maybe this answer is better in terms of speed and overhead. Yet, the other solution is certainly faster coded and easier to read. Is that really worth the potential benefit?

### Update:

In short, the following sub is a re-write of your original post and does exactly the same. Yet, it does not make use of variant variables (which reduces overhead and is therefore favorable).

```
Dim lngItem As Long
Dim strArray() As String

strArray = Split("Sheet2/Sheet3/Sheet5/Sheet6", "/")

For lngItem = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strArray(lngItem)).Visible = True
Next lngItem
```

Comment: Can you explain what Split(Join(arr1, "/") & "/" & Join(arr2, "/"), "/") does? Can it be saved as a variable?

Comment: I just updated the first solution and made it much more elaborate (including a message box showing you the intermediary string). Furthermore, I added some background information on how `split` and `array` work and how they differ. Since this made the first solution very long I added to the bottom a new code segment which does essentially the same as yours. Yet, without the `variant` variables and without `For Each` or the `Array` function.

Comment: Looks like an efficient way for concatenating arrays in VBA. Also, it seems that VBA is not that useful as other languages for processing arrays in general, although VBA is good at working with cells and ranges in "array fashion". Still, both answers are for specialized cases where you have limited amount of arrays. So what to do if we have dynamic amount of arrays? Does it mean that such a solution even would be better where you create a temporary worksheet and put all arrays' content there to process?